How to enable multiline support for custom text logs in a Data Collection Rule in Azure
What I try to do:
gather logs from a virtual machine in Azure using Azure Monitoring Agent. The log file is a plain text file with timestamps. Each log message is a multi-line text blog.
What succeeded:
basically I managed to gather the logs.
It's just that each line of the log file was treated as a log entry and written into a custom table in my log analytics workspace.
For that a data collection rule, a data collection endpoint and a custom table were created and the virtual machine is with the data collection rule associated.
The creation of the data collection rule was done with powerCLI.
What is expected:
Multi-line logs are treated as one log entry. The delimiter would be timestamps instead of end of line.
Question:
According to the following doc, multi-line support is available. Unfortunately, I couldn't find more detailed documentation or examples. Any help please?

Multiline support that uses a time stamp to delimited events is now available. You must use a resource management template deployment until support is added in the Portal UI.

Much appreciation in advance!
